# How to use react-native-mmkv in my react native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use react-native-mmkv package in my react native app can anyone can help me to do that? i installed the package and followed some steps on docs but i cant able to setup it properly i am using latest version of rn cli and react-native-mmkv how can i use that in my project I try to do MMKV.set('user', JSON.stringify(data)); its not working its giving me type errors How to initialize mmkv storage ?

import { MMKV } from 'react-native-mmkv';

export const storage = new MMKV()

const Login = ({ navigation }) => {

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

const handleLogin = () => {
    if (email == '' || password == '') {
        alert('Please enter email and password')
    }
    else {
        setLoading(true)
        fetch('http://10.0.2.2:3000/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email,
                password
            })
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(async data => {
                console.log(data)
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
                if (data.error) {
                    setLoading(false)
                    alert(data.error)
                }
                else if (data.message == 'Successfully Signed In') {
                    setLoading(false)
                    await MMKV.set('user', JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setLoading(false)
                alert(err)
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
}

return (
   // ...
)
```

}

export default Login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initiate store as

```
export const storage = new MMKV()
```

you call it using exported variable, so

```
instead: MMKV.set()
do: storage.set()
```

Comment: But do i need to do export const storage = new MMKV()
 everytime I use mmkv? i am using AsyncStorage in 16 files should I change every  AsyncStorageto MMkv?

Comment: no, you should do it once in your app.
you can do it in custom file like storage.js and then import it whenever you need it